# How to filter foreignkey pointing to self

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
     (...)
     leader = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name ='leader_set')
```

And now I'd like to find People, who are leaders to themselves.

sth like this:

```
own_leaders = Person.objects.filter(leader__isself=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to reference a field, so:

```
own_leaders = Person.objects.filter(leader=F('pk'))
```

Comment: I was hope, that it would be special contstruction, but of course - this perfectly works.